# Не могу убрать [] при выводе списка с словаря

Tags: python, json

Я написал бота для парсинга маркета для игры CS:GO, и телеграм бота к нему. Я беру цену, название, и стикеры, если стикеров нет то не записываю, а стикеры я записываю в список. При выводе информации о предмете, когда есть стикеры то выводится список стикеров но с скобками, и кавычками, помогите мне их убрать пожалуйста.

Сообщение в телеграме где нужно убрать скобки

```
['Наклейка: ALEX (золотая) | Берлин 2019', 'Наклейка: ALEX (золотая) | Берлин 2019', 'Наклейка: ALEX (золотая) | Берлин 2019', 'Наклейка: ALEX (золотая) | Берлин 2019']
```

Как я беру информацию с json файла

```
    with open('resultpmarketcsgo.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        itemlist = json.load(file)
    for item in itemlist:
        if item.get('sticker_url') is not None:
            text_ss = f'{hlink(item.get("title_item"), item.get("url_item"))} \n {item.get("price_item")} \n {item.get("sticker_url")}'
            await message.answer(text_ss)
        else:
            text_bs = f'{hlink(item.get("title_item"), item.get("url_item"))} \n {hbold(item.get("price_item"))}'
            await message.answer(text_bs)
```

json файл с информацией

```
  {
        "title_item": "ПП-19 «Бизон» | Space Cat (Поношенное)",
        "price_item": "37.95 RUB",
        "url_item": "https://market.csgo.com/item/4726068058-188530139-PP-Bizon%20%7C%20Space%20Cat%20%28Well-Worn%29/"
    },
    {
        "title_item": "SG 553 | Заросшие руины (После полевых испытаний)",
        "price_item": "15.6 RUB",
        "url_item": "https://market.csgo.com/item/4841323188-519977179-SG%20553%20%7C%20Lush%20Ruins%20%28Field-Tested%29/",
        "sticker_url": [
            "Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019",
            "Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019",
            "Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sticker = ' '.join(item.get("sticker_url"))
text_ss = f'{hlink(item.get("title_item"), item.get("url_item"))}\n{item.get("price_item")}\n{sticker}'
```

пример(пайтон 3.8 и выше)

```
itemlist = {"title_item": "ПП-19 «Бизон» | Space Cat (Поношенное)",
       "price_item": "37.95 RUB",
       "url_item": "https://market.csgo.com/item/4726068058-188530139-PP-Bizon%20%7C%20Space%20Cat%20%28Well-Worn%29/"
       }, \
      {"title_item": "SG 553 | Заросшие руины (После полевых испытаний)",
       "price_item": "15.6 RUB",
       "url_item": "https://market.csgo.com/item/4841323188-519977179-SG%20553%20%7C%20Lush%20Ruins%20%28Field-Tested%29/",
       "sticker_url": ["Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019", "Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019", "Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019"
                       ]
       }

for item in itemlist:
      print('-'*50)
      sticker = ''
      if stic := item.get('sticker_url'):
            sticker = '\n' + '\n'.join(stic)
      text_ss = f'{item.get("title_item")}\n{item.get("url_item")}\n{item.get("price_item")}{sticker}'
      print(text_ss)
```

вывод

```
ПП-19 «Бизон» | Space Cat (Поношенное)
https://market.csgo.com/item/4726068058-188530139-PP-Bizon%20%7C%20Space%20Cat%20%28Well-Worn%29/
37.95 RUB
--------------------------------------------------
SG 553 | Заросшие руины (После полевых испытаний)
https://market.csgo.com/item/4841323188-519977179-SG%20553%20%7C%20Lush%20Ruins%20%28Field-Tested%29/
15.6 RUB
Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019
Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019
Наклейка: RpK | Берлин 2019
```